# Rouché's theorem: exercise

Tags: complex-analysis

Is a exercise of the book "functions of one complex variable I" by John Conway, which I have not been able to solve. Says the following:

Let $G$ be a bounded region and let $f$ be an analytic function in $G$ and continue in $\overline{G}$. Prove that if there exists a constant $c\geq0$ such that $|f(z)|=c$ for all $z$ on the boundary of $G$, then either $f$ is a constant function or $f$ has a zero in $G$.

Comment: If $c = 0$, then $f$ is immediately constant and has a zero in $G$.  If $c > 0$, then $f(z)$ has no zeros $G$, and one has to show that $f$ is constant in $G$, and I would suggest looking here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_modulus_principle

Not sure, though, how to do this using Rouche's theorem.

Comment: @avs If I have the same version of the book by Conway this question is after the Maximum modulus principle.

Comment: @mfl, thanks for the feedback.  I don't have Conway's book at all.:)  (Nor would I recommend anything other than H. Cartan's book on analytic functions, but this is besides the point.)  I was just going from first principles, and the Maximum Principle came up.:)